# AsyncTask setting priority

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask(.execute())` with an `onPostExecute` method. This method starts another `AsyncTask(.execute())` that needs to be done before continuing the execution of the first `onPostExecute`. Is it possible to pause the first thread and to wait for the second thread to finish? I need the result from the second `postExecute` method in order to finish the first `postExecute`.

An example below:

```
public class RetrieveData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String linieNoua = "";
            String crlf = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while((linieNoua = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(linieNoua);
                sb.append(crlf);
            }
            conn.disconnect();
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

RetrieveData retrieveData = new RetrieveData() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (s != null) {
               retrieveTransport(transportRegNr);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.login_server_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    retrieveData.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"http://192.168.0.101:3000/route/" + prefs.getString("email",null));
}

private void retrieveTransport(String regNr){

    RetrieveData retrieveData = new RetrieveData() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (s != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

                    String model = jsonObject.getString("model");
                    String regNr = jsonObject.getString("regNr");
                    int type = jsonObject.getInt("type");
                    int seats = jsonObject.getInt("seats");

                    t = new Transport(model,regNr,null,seats,type);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.login_server_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    retrieveData.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"http://192.168.0.101:3000/transport/registryNr/" + regNr);
}
```

If I use the `execute` method, `onPostExecute` from `retrieveTransport(String regNr)` is never called. If I use `executeOnExecutor`, they are running simultaneously, and that's not good, either. I need to finish the first `retrieveTransport`; without that, I can't continue the first `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

use

> getStatus()

checks whether the the AsyncTask is pending, running, or finished.and when finsh start your new task.like:

```
if(retrieveTransport.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){
    // My AsyncTask has not started yet
}

if(retrieveTransport.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
    // My AsyncTask is currently doing work in doInBackground()
}

if(retrieveTransport.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
    // START NEW TASK HERE
}
```

example for your app:

```
        if (retrieveTransport!= null && retrieveTransport.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
           //START retrieveData TASK HERE
        }
        else
        {
          //IGNORE 
        }
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but I can't ignore that data, I tried to put a while loop but app crashing....